# Where are my "revert" options in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, revert

I'm working with a new install and repository in TortoiseSVN. I made some changes and moved some files around, but right-clicking and bringing up the context menu and/or revision log does not provide me with any of the "revert" options mentioned in the daily use guide.

How can I give myself access to the "revert" options when they go missing?

I right-clicked the "TortoiseSVN" shell program icon → Settings, then checked box "Revert" to add that option to the "Right Click/Context Menu" options list. It is still not showing up after restarts.

(See context menu...no "revert" option displaying below.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I get `Revert...` by right-clicking on any file or directory with modifications, and then choosing `TortoiseSVN ▶` which opens a second-level menu including `Revert...`. This is, I believe the way it comes ‘out of the box’. Does that not work for you?

Comment: No, I had to actually go into the settings, add "revert" to the context menu, and save. On my remote machine, the context menu still hasn't updated and it's been over an hour. Local machine I did this and I was able to select "revert" from the right click/context menu as expected. Version info: TortoiseSVN 1.8.11, Build 26392 - 64 Bit , 2015/03/19 18:50:20
Subversion 1.8.13, -release
apr 1.5.1
apr-util 1.5.4
serf 1.3.8
OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
zlib 1.2.8

Comment: Did you modify your settings on the remote machine? Tortoise settings are local to the (Subversion-) client where it is installed (and your login). But it is really weird that it does not work out of the box – are you sure the version is right for your hardware (it is exactly the same as the version I am using on MS Windows 7 SP1)? Are you clicking in the Windows Explorer (not the repository explorer)? (Sorry if these sound obvious, but it’s hard to think what the problem can be!)

Comment: Amazingly, yes I did, and restarted the remote machine. This usually works for me when the icon overlays are being slow to update.

Comment: Your context menu looks like that in the Repository browser. There your options are different. You normally revert changes in the Working Copy (and preferably build and test them!), and then commit. To revert changes in the WC, you open it in the **Windows** Explorer, and right-click there.

Comment: The settings you are changing, though they say “**cascaded** context menu” actually move the checked entries to the top-level context menu (in Windows Explorer), as the mouse-over text says.

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be that you are using the context menu (right-click) in the TortoiseSVN repository browser, rather than that in Windows Explorer, which looks different even in the repository directories — this is recognisable from your screen-shot.

The repo-browser context menu gives you options applying to the repository rather to than the working copy. You do not normally want to revert directly in the repository, but rather to check out to a Working Copy, revert there (and preferably build and test the result!), and then commit.

#### Reverting in your working copy

Once you have checked out a working copy to a directory on your (Windows) Subversion client, you can then open your working copy in the **Windows** Explorer and thence access `Revert...` by right-clicking on any file or directory with modifications, and then choosing `TortoiseSVN ▶` which opens a second-level menu including `Revert....` This is the way it comes out of the box. If you want to revert a file or directory to an older version, you will find useful options if you open the `Log...` dialogue and right-click on a revision or one of the files in a revision.

#### TortoiseSVN settings

The TortoiseSVN settings you are using only affect the context menu for Windows Explorer, not for the repository browser. These settings are local to the (Subversion-) client on which TortoiseSVN is installed (and your login), so you may need to change them on multiple machines, though you should not need to modify them to be able to revert in your working copy. Although these settings are described as “cascaded context menu”, they actually move the checked entries *out* of the cascaded menu to the top-level context menu (in Windows Explorer), as the mouse-over text says.

#### Overlay updating

The overlays in Windows Explorer can be slow to update on a busy system or with many or large working copies. In this case doing a TortoiseSVN `Clean up...` on your working copy and ticking “update overlays” usually helps.

Comment: yes, I want to revert false deletes and such. I want "revert" in the repo browser. And, I can see this feature on the context menu and in the repo browser of tortoise svn on my local machine. RDing into the machine with another instance of tortoise svn is not updating this feature after changes are being made on that machine.

Comment: and btw this is the same version of tortoisesvn on both machines I'm talking about.